# Where is my system overdetermined?

Tags: differential-equations

I am solving a system of two PDEs originating from the heat transfer area. There are two dependent variables `u[t,x]` and `T[t,x]`. Here `T`is the temperature, `t` is time and `x` is the spatial coordinate. Equations are as follows:

```
eq = {D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] - T[t, x]*u[t, x] + u[t, x]^3 - u[t, x]^5, 

   D[T[t, x], t] == D[T[t, x], {x, 2}] + 10*D[u[t, x], x]^2};
```

For each variable I have two boundary conditions at the edges of the x interval: x=0 and x=100.

In addition there are two initial conditions: one for u and one for T.

The list of the boundary and initial conditions is:

```
bic = {u[t, 0] == u0, u[t, 100] == 0, T[t, 0] == 0.1, T[t, 100] == 0.1, 
   u[0, x] == u0*(Tanh[4 - x] + 1)/(Tanh[4] + 1), T[0, x] == 0.1};
```

Parameter `u0`is

```
u0 = Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 T[t, x]]]/Sqrt[2];
```

I solve the equations straightforwardly:

```
sl = NDSolve[{eq, bic}, {u, T}, {x, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 300}]
```

and get the error message: "There are fewer dependent variables, `{T[t,x],u[t,x]}`, than
equations, so the system is overdetermined", which I do not understand.

If I remove the variable `T[t,x]` from the system:

```
Clear[eq, bic, u0];
u0 = Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - 4*0.1]]/Sqrt[2];
eq = D[u[t, x], t] == 
   D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] - 0.1*u[t, x] + u[t, x]^3 - u[t, x]^5;
bic = {u[t, 0] == u0, u[t, 100] == 0, 
   u[0, x] == u0*(Tanh[4 - x] + 1)/(Tanh[4] + 1)};
sl = NDSolve[{eq, bic}, u, {x, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 300}]
```

It immediately exhibits the solution.

Any idea, what's wrong with my first code?

Comment: In ` D[T[t, x], t] == D[T[t, x] {x, 2}]` there is a missing comma.

Comment: @ Daniel Huber Yes, you are right, but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: The initial and boundary conditions for `u` are incorrect.  Try `bic = {u[t, 0] == u0 /. x -> 0, u[t, 100] == 0, T[t, 0] == 0.1, T[t, 100] == 0.1, u[0, x] == (u0 /. t -> 0)*(Tanh[4 - x] + 1)/(Tanh[4] + 1), T[0, x] == 0.1};`.  Why this triggers the particular error message you mentioned is unclear.

Comment: @ bbgodfrey Thank you, this solved the problem.